# essential self-adjointess for operators that can be factorized as $TT^*$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be Hilbert spaces, $D$ be a dense subspace of $X$, $T:D\to Y$ be a linear operator, $\tilde{D}:=T(D)$. Assume $T^*T:D\to X$ to be essentially self-adjoint and the generated semigroup $(e^{-tT^*T})_{t\ge 0}$ to leave $D$ invariant. If additionally $T^*(\tilde{D})\subset D$, does it follow that the operator $TT^*:\tilde{D}\to Y$ is essentially self-adjoint as well?